# Trying to do a sum on data tables, but its only suming first page

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to sum columns in a data table. But it is only suming the first page?
The two variables `Requiredone` and `Bookedtwo` only sum the values from the first page of the data, not the entire data set :s

```
    var sTable = $('.datatable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "aaSorting": [[1, "desc"]],
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": CycleTimeReport,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sName": "one", "sClass": "ellipsis" },
        { "sName": "two", "sClass": "ellipsis" }
    ],
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        var data = new Object();
        data.jsonAOData = JSON.stringify(aoData);
        dataToSend = data;

        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            url: sSource,
            data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
            success: function (msg) {
                fnCallback(msg);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (document.Invoice.hostname == "localhost") {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {

            var Requiredone = 0;
            var Bookedtwo = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < aaData.length; i++) {
                Requiredone+= aaData[i][2] * 1;
                Bookedtwo += aaData[i][3] * 1;
            }
},
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "_INPUT_"
    },
    "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
    },
    "bSortCellsTop": true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using server-side processing of the data. So your datatable-object only has the data for the currently displayed page. You have to implement the sum on the server-side and add it to the JSON-response or do it in an extra ajax-request.

Another option would be to disable the server-side processing and pre-populate the table element or fill the aaData-property of the datatales-settings with a json object containing all data.

Comment: Whats the easiest way of removing the server side processing and loading the entire data and then not going back to server?

Comment: Set `bServerSide`and `bProcessing`to `false`. Then you have several options to fill the data of the datatable. 1. You could pre-populate the table-element with all rows. 2. Fill the `aaData`-property of the datatales-settings with a json object containing all data.